# Denoising missing from Cycles scene panel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I can't find the denoising options on Blender 2.79, even though I'm using Cycles Render. Does anyone have any idea of why this occurs, and how to bring it back?

[image: denoising missing on Scene tab]

Comment: You are on version 2.78. There is  no denoiser on that version. Use 2.79

Answer (score 1):

On the screen blender 2.78 without denoiser.

[image]

You should [download](https://www.blender.org/download/) 2.79b to have denoising function